# File and text processing using bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I have two text files. hash_only.txt and final_output.txt
hash_only.txt looks like below.

```
193548
401125
401275
```

final_output.txt looks like below.

```
193548      1199687744  5698758206701808640
193548      1216464960  5698758206761818112
193548      1216464960  5698758206778417152
193548      4236691520  5698758206778945280
401125      2138607488  5698762375908890880
401125       863932288  5698762375909423360
401125      3884158848  5698762375910044160
401125      2609483648  5698762375911032320
```

I am trying to write a loop which does the follows.

```
for i in `cat hash_only.txt` ;
do
    for j in `cat final_output.txt` ;
            do
                    if [ $i -eq $j ]
                    then
                            echo $i $j      
                    fi
            done
 done;
```

For all the values in hash_only.txt such as 193548,401125 etc I want to extract column 2,3 from the file 'final_output.txt' where column 1 matches 193548,401125 etc and output 
column 2,3 to print_193548, print_401125 etc.

How do I do that.In the above code I need to put some code inside the then part.But I can't figure that out since I am not very proficient in bash.

Edit:

I have now modified the my script to look likefor i in `cat hash_only.txt` ;

```
do
        for j in `cat final_output.txt` ;
                do
                        if [ $i -eq $j ]
                        then
                                gawk 'FNR==NR
                                        { hash[$1]  
                                          next 
                                        }
                                       $1 in hash  { 
                                        print $2,$3 >> "print_"$1; 
                                }' hash_only.txt final_output.txt
                        fi
                done
done;
```

It is not creating any files named print_[0-9]*.I can't understand why not?

Comment: So you want to create a bunch of files, right?  One for each distinct value in the first file?

Comment: yes.that is exactly what I want.

Comment: The `gawk` command will do all the job. `if...else`/`for...loop` can be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
FNR==NR {
    hash[$1]
    next
}
$1 in hash {
    printf("%s\t%s\n", $2, $3) > "print_"$1;
}' hash_only.txt final_output.txt
```

What a magic, my solution is almost identical to peter's.

Comment: are you suggesting that I add this code after the if then part in my code??I tried it it doesn't seem to work.It just printed out a series of values.

Comment: Copy and paste to your terminal. It'll create two files(`print_193548`, `print_401125`) in the current directory.

Comment: The `>>` should be `>` (it works a bit differently in AWK than the shell).

Comment: Thanks very much.it worked.But I want to adjust the spacing between the $2 and $3 so that I can give this as an input to gnuplot.Any ideas I have tried '\t' " " etc doesn't seem to work ?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
nawk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}($1 in a){print $2,$3>$1}' hash_only.txt  final_output.txt
```

This will actually create a file with name as the first field and store the output in the way you have requested.

Comment: You can omit the parentheses.

Answer (score -1):

```
cat hash_only.txt | while read FNAME; do { cat final_output.txt |grep ${FNAME} |awk '{$1="";}1' > print_${FNAME}; } ; done ; find ./print_* -type f -size 0 -delete
```

```
$ ls ./print_??????
./print_193548  ./print_401125
```

```
$ cat ./print_193548
 1199687744 5698758206701808640
 1216464960 5698758206761818112
 1216464960 5698758206778417152
 4236691520 5698758206778945280
```

```
$ cat ./print_401125
 2138607488 5698762375908890880
 863932288 5698762375909423360
 3884158848 5698762375910044160
 2609483648 5698762375911032320
```